# Undefined constant 'App\Product' when i run php artisan db:seed laravel6

Tags: laravel

i'm using laravel6 and i want to create 100 products in table products.bit its give me error.

hi, i'm using laravel6 and i want to create 100 products in table products.bit its give me error.

**ProductFactory.php**

```
<?php

/** @var \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory $factory */

use App\Product; 
use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(Product::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'title'=> $faker->sentence(5),
        'description' => paragraph()
    ];
});
```

**databaseSeed.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder 
{
    /**
     * Seed the application's database.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        // $this->call(UsersTableSeeder::class);
        factory(App\Product,100)->create();
    }
}
```

**tableproducts**

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->text('description');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Comment: @TsaiKoga thx for answer but where i will add  use \App\Product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your wrong `factory(App\Product, 100)->create();` change this to 
   `factory(App\Product::class, 100)->create();`

in **databaseSeed.php:**

```
 <?php

 use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

 class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder 
{
/**
 * Seed the application's database.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function run()
 {
    // $this->call(UsersTableSeeder::class);
    factory(App\Product::class, 100)->create();
  }
}
```

and other error in **ProductFactory.php:** 
change `paragraph()` to `$facker->paragraph()`

```
<?php

/** @var \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory $factory */

 use App\Product; 
  use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(Product::class, function (Faker $faker) {
return [
    'title'=> $faker->sentence(5),
    'description' => $faker->paragraph()
];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

include your Product model in databaseSeed.php.

```
   <?php

    use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
    use App\Product; 
    class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder 
    {
         /**
         * Seed the application's database.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function run()
        {
            // $this->call(UsersTableSeeder::class);
            factory(Product,100)->create();
        }
   }
```